# many to many relationship : org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to set up a many to many bidirectional relationship with JPA based on this example : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

I m getting a

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: T_ITEM, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(itemHikes)]

If anyone can help me on that, here is the source code below:

Class Item

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Set<ItemHike> itemHikes = new HashSet<ItemHike>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<ItemHike> getItemHikes() {
        return this.itemHikes;
    }

    public void setItemHikes(Set<ItemHike> itemHikes) {
        this.itemHikes = itemHikes;
    }
}
```

Class Hike

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_HIKE")
public class Hike implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private List<ItemHike> itemHikes = new ArrayList<ItemHike>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.hike", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ItemHike> getItemHikes() {
        return this.itemHikes;
    }

    public void setItemHikes(List<ItemHike> itemHikes) {
        this.itemHikes = itemHikes;
    }
}
```

Class ItemHike

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ITEM_HIKE")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.item", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iditem")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.hike", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idlist")) })


public class ItemHike implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemHikePK pk;

    private int quantity;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to THike

    @Transient
    public Item getItem() {
        return getPk().getItem();
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        getPk().setItem(item);
    }


    @Transient
    public Hike getHike() {
        return getPk().getHike();
    }

    public void setHike(Hike hike) {
        getPk().setHike(hike);
    }

    public ItemHike() {
    }

    public ItemHikePK getPk() {
        return this.pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ItemHikePK pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Class ItemHikePk

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemHikePK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Item item;
    private Hike hike;

    @ManyToOne
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Hike getHike() {
        return hike;
    }

    public void setHike(Hike hike) {
        this.hike = hike;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a similiar question !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/how-to-make-this-tutorial-work-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at)

You're setting @Anottations on Fields and too on Getters, that's wrong, You must put annotations on Fields OR on Getters Methods.

Wrong way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Set<ItemHike> itemHikes = new HashSet<ItemHike>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<ItemHike> getItemHikes() {
        return this.itemHikes;
    }

    public void setItemHikes(Set<ItemHike> itemHikes) {
        this.itemHikes = itemHikes;
    }
}
```

Correct:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ItemHike> itemHikes = new HashSet<ItemHike>(0);

    public Set<ItemHike> getItemHikes() {
        return this.itemHikes;
    }

    public void setItemHikes(Set<ItemHike> itemHikes) {
        this.itemHikes = itemHikes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't find a similar answer on stakoverflow. It's working. But at runtime I m getting a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'itemhikes1_.item' in 'field list'. Actually, the field mentionned is idiom, not 'item'. It's referenced by pk.item.

Comment: You say that the field in your MySql table is 'idiom', well then when you declare the '@JoinColumn' in '@AssociationOverride' you should put the correct field name, now you have: '@JoinColumn(name = "iditem")', you should have: '@JoinColumn(name = "idiom")'.

Comment: sorry, my tablet transformed the word iditem to idiom, i didn't see it. The field is iditem. that's why i don't understand why it can't see this field.

Comment: Oh I see, again you have a problem with the Access Strategy, in your ItemHike Class, you're mixing Field Access and getter property access; You Have '@EmbeddedId' on private ItemHikePK pk and then you put '@Transient' on getters.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the @OneToMany annotation from `getItemHikes()` to the `itemHikes` field. If you want your annotations to be sometimes on the fields and sometimes on the getters, you need to use the @Access annotation. If you don't use it, all annotations need to be either on the fields or on the getters, but not a mix of both.