# Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: …, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(…)]

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Trying to associate Messages OneToMany Comments but an error occurs:

```
An Error Occurred:
[PersistenceUnit: persistence] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: message, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(comments)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment.java:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;

    public Comment(){}

    public Comment(String descricao){ 
    this.descricao=descricao;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Comment other = (Comment) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Message:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cor;
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany
    public List<Comentario> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public String getCor() {
        return this.cor;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Message other = (Message ) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/how-to-make-this-tutorial-work-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at)

Comment: Why do you have different types for your List? On your getter you have Comentario and on your setter you have Comment.