# SpringBoot+Hibernate Relationship issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, mapping

I have an issue with the relationships of 3 entities. I was trying to have an inheritance heriarchy but within the child class I refer to a List of my Parent class objects as an attribute. So I would like my child class entity to be a mapper table, in which shows the association between it and it's parent. In doing this I was running into a bunch of relationship issues
I've created a sample project emulating the functionality.

**Automobile.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Automobile implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long Id;

@OneToOne
private Manufacturer manufacturer;

@OneToOne
private AutomobileType autotype;

@OneToOne
private LoanerCar loanerCarID;

private String vin;

//Getters and Setters, Arg Constructors, No-Arg Constructor, toString
}
```

**LoanerCar.java**

```
package com.example.demo.domains;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class LoanerCar extends Automobile{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private Timestamp dateLoaned;
private Timestamp dateReceived;

@OneToMany
private List<Automobile> alist;

//Getters and Setters, Arg Constructors, No-Arg Constructor, toString
}
```

**TotaledCar.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class TotaledCar extends Automobile {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<LoanerCar> eligibleLoaners;
```

//Getters and Setters, Arg Constructors, No-Arg Constructor, toString
    }

**AutomobileBaseRepository.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import com.example.demo.domains.Automobile;
import com.example.demo.domains.Manufacturer;   

@NoRepositoryBean

public interface AutomobileBaseRepository<T extends Automobile> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
List<T> findByLoanerCarID(Long id);

List<T> findByVinAndManufacturerAndLoanerCarID(String vin, Manufacturer manfacturer, Long id);
}
```

Automobile, TotaledCar, LoanerCar repositories extend the AutomobileBaseRespoistory, and has no methods.

**LoaanerController.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.domains.LoanerCar;
import com.example.demo.domains.Manufacturer;
import com.example.demo.domains.TotaledCar;
import com.example.demo.repositories.LoanerCarRepository;
import com.example.demo.repositories.ManufacturerRepository;
import com.example.demo.repositories.TotaledCarRepository;

@RestController
public class LoanerController {

    @Autowired
    LoanerCarRepository loanerRepo;

    @Autowired
    TotaledCarRepository totaledCarRepo;

    @Autowired
    ManufacturerRepository manRepo;


    @RequestMapping(value="/loaner/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<LoanerCar> loaners(){
        List<LoanerCar> list = loanerRepo.findAll();
        return list;
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value="/loaner/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public LoanerCar getLoaner(@PathVariable Long id){
        LoanerCar loanerCar= loanerRepo.findOne(id);
        return loanerCar;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/loaner", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String response(@RequestParam("vin") String vin, @RequestParam("manufacturer") Long manfuacturerId, @RequestParam("loanerId") Long loanerId){
        Manufacturer manObj = manRepo.findById(manfuacturerId);

        List<LoanerCar> loanerList = loanerRepo.findByLoanerCarID(loanerId);
        List<TotaledCar> tlist = totaledCarRepo.findByVinAndManufacturerAndLoanerCarID(vin, manObj, loanerId);

        for (TotaledCar junk : tlist){
            loanerList.addAll(junk.getEligibleLoaners());
        }

        String strlist = loanerList.toString();
        return strlist;
    }
}
```

So the flow of this mapping is suppose to be from when I add an Automobile it will have an loanerId of null by default. And when I assign a value to the loanerId it is mapped to the LoanerCar table, in which has a AutomobileId from the parent class/table and a loanerId resides in the LoanerCar class/table. So in the LoanerCar table the loanerId is tied to a list of Automobiles in which are eligible for LoanerCars. So Automobile has one loanerId, and that loanerId can many automobiles.And my controller method will just get me a list of both totaled and loaner cars. I know it sounds confusing but I get this is what I'm trying to achieve.

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringJpaInheritanceRelationshipsApplication.main(SpringJpaInheritanceRelationshipsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: totaled_car, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(eligible_loaners)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass.validate(JoinedSubclass.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As a side note, have you tried using spring-data instead of Hibernate since you are already using spring library?

Comment: Yea I'm using spring data jpa, through the use of repositories. Can you be more specific. I believe spring data has the relationship annotations as well. But I'm confused on where to put them. given the task at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using field access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above

```
private List<LoanerCar> eligibleLoaners;
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, I have a side question what if I wanted to use the Id of the Automobile class and a field from the LoanerCar class as a composite key, I read about forcedDiscrimnator but I can't find the dependency to use it. Also, it creates the List elements as a separate table, is it possible to keep that data within it's corresponding table?

Comment: NP. i think, you should ask it as a new question. By the way, mark plz this answer as accepted.