# How to create persisting hierarchical structure with states

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, corda

I’ve been trying to create a persisting hierarchical state structure using https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/api-persistence.html?highlight=generatemappedobject#persisting-hierarchical-data as a guide.

My structure is the following. I have a ServiceState that can have 0..* ServiceDataStates. In the future ServiceDataState can have as well 0..* usePurposeStates but for now that can be ignored.

You can see my current schemas and states. My corda version is 3.3

```
object ServiceSchema

@CordaSerializable
object ServiceSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
    schemaFamily = ServiceSchema.javaClass,
    version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentServiceState::class.java,
        ServiceDataSchemaV1.PersistentServiceDataState::class.java)) {

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "service_state")
    class PersistentServiceState (

        @Column(name = "linear_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var linearId: UUID,

        @Column(name = "account_operator", nullable = false)
        var accountOoperator: String,

        @Column(name = "service_provider", nullable = false)
        var serviceProvider: String,

        @Column(name = "service_name", nullable = false)
        var serviceName: String,

        @Column(name = "service_description", nullable = false)
        var serviceDescription: String,

        @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false)
        var dateCreated: LocalDate,

        @JoinColumns(
            JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
            JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))
        var serviceDataStates: MutableList<ServiceDataState>?,

        @Column(name = "service_partner_name", nullable = true)
        var servicePartners: String?

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this(
            UUID.randomUUID(),
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            LocalDate.now(),
            mutableListOf(),
            ""
        )
    }
}
```

```
object ServiceDataSchema

@CordaSerializable
object ServiceDataSchemaV1: MappedSchema(
    schemaFamily = ServiceDataSchema.javaClass,
    version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(ServiceDataSchemaV1.PersistentServiceDataState::class.java,
        ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentServiceState::class.java,
        UsePurposeSchemaV1.PersistentUsePurposeState::class.java)) {

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "servicedata_state")
    class PersistentServiceDataState(

        @Column(name = "linearid", unique = true, nullable = false)
        var linearId: UUID,

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        var name: String,

        @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
        var type: String,

        @Column(name = "usepurposes")
        var usePurposes: UUID,

        @Column(name = "api_schema", nullable = false)
        var apiSchema: String,

        @Column(name = "api_transfer_terms", nullable = false)
        var apiTransferTerms: String,

        @Column(name = "servicedata_party_name", nullable = true)
        var parties: String?,

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentServiceState::class)
        var persistentServiceState: ServiceState?

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this(
            UUID.randomUUID(),
            "",
            "",
            UUID.randomUUID(),
            "",
            "",
            "",
            null
        )
    }

}
```

```
data class ServiceState(
    val accountOperator: Party,
    val serviceProvider: Party,
    val serviceName: String,
    val serviceDescription: String,
    val dateCreated: LocalDate,
    val serviceDataStates: MutableList<ServiceDataState>,
    val servicePartners: MutableList<Party>,
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
) : LinearState, QueryableState {

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(ServiceSchemaV1)

    override val participants get() =
        listOf(accountOperator, serviceProvider)

    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema) {
            is ServiceSchemaV1 -> ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentServiceState(
                this.linearId.id,
                this.accountOperator.name.toString(),
                this.serviceProvider.name.toString(),
                this.serviceName,
                this.serviceDescription,
                this.dateCreated,
                this.serviceDataStates,
                this.servicePartners[0]?.name.toString()
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    fun serviceCopyWithTodaysDate() = copy(dateCreated = LocalDate.now())

    fun addServiceData(
        serviceDataList: MutableList<ServiceDataState>,
        id: UniqueIdentifier
    ) = copy(
        serviceDataStates = serviceDataList,
        linearId = id
    )

    fun addPartners(servicePartners: MutableList<Party>, id: UniqueIdentifier) = copy(
            servicePartners = servicePartners,
            linearId = id
    )
}
```

```
data class ServiceDataState(
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(),
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val usePurposes: MutableList<UniqueIdentifier>,
    val service: ServiceState,
    val apiSchema: String,
    val apiTransferTerms: String,
    val parties: MutableList<Party>
) : LinearState, QueryableState {

    override val participants: List<Party> get() =
        parties

    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema) {
            is ServiceDataSchemaV1 -> ServiceDataSchemaV1.PersistentServiceDataState(
                this.linearId.id,
                this.name,
                this.type,
                this.usePurposes[0]?.id,
                this.apiSchema,
                this.apiTransferTerms,
                this.parties[0]?.name.toString(),
                this.service
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(ServiceDataSchemaV1)
```

I don't know what I am missing. When I'm starting my nodes I get the following stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: service_state, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(serviceDataStates)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.6.Final.jar:5.2.6.Final]
```

Comment: Have you looked at other stackoverflow posts since this looks like a hibernate issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236527/could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set-at-table

Comment: Thanks, I checked those links and to my eyes it looks like Im adhering to Field-based access in both of those schemas. I also updated my code (changed parties type to string in both schemas) but Im still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a hibernate issue, specifically one in which you have to add some annotations to clear out the issue.

in the case of a list for your specific issue maybe something like this?

```
@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
private List<Integer> countries;
```

Take a look at these posts as well they might be able to help out.

[org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164123/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set)

[org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: College, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(students)]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at)