# Design pattern Strategy ? how to map a class and interface

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to get the strategy pattern design working with mysql.

I can't manage relational mapping ..
Here is my code:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
public class Nobody implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Displacement displacement = new walk();
    // how do you walk
    public void sayWalking() {
        displacement.move();
    }
    public Nobody() {
    }

    public Nobody(String name, Displacement displacement) {
        this.name = name;
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Displacement getDisplacement() {
        return displacement;
    }

    public void setDisplacement(Displacement displacement) {
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "nobody{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", displacement=" + displacement +
                '}';
    }
}

import com.example.demo.model.Nobody;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface NobodyDAO extends JpaRepository<Nobody, Long> {
}

public interface Displacement {
    void move();
}
public class walk implements  Displacement {
    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I walk with 2 members");
    }
}

public class NotWalk implements Displacement {
    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I don't walk, but I use a wheelchair");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Nobody nobody = new Nobody();
        nobody.setName("test");
        nobody.sayWalking();
        nobody.setDisplacement(new NotWalk());
        nobody.sayWalking();
    }
```

I can't understand, nor can I make the link between the class and the interface

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-06 01:55:15.625 ERROR 276196 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nobodyDAO' defined in com.example.demo.dao.NobodyDAO defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.example.demo.model.Nobody.displacement references an unknown entity: com.example.demo.model.Displacement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:623) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:611) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.example.demo.model.Nobody.displacement references an unknown entity: com.example.demo.model.Displacement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.example.demo.model.Nobody.displacement references an unknown entity: com.example.demo.model.Displacement
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

another question, I don't know mongodb at all, but does this kind of pattern not work better on mongodb? or mysql and mongodb, with spring boot, it's the same thing?

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your code. Could you perhaps edit it so its as close to complete as possible? You could look at this [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416970/onetomany-manytoone-mapping-spring-boot-hibernate) to frame your question better.

Comment: I updated my post. Make connections between class, I get there. But this is a class with an interface, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. I may have a problem with the design of the pattern. I discovered the pattern strategy; but without the jpa, it works

Comment: I still haven't found the solution to my problem ...