# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name finance_finance_id was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Hi I am struggling to find what is wrong in my code I have searched and tried to find the answers to it, I also checked my database to see if my naming conventions matched the one I have in my models and also double checked if the @Column in my BreakDown model matched the @JoinColumn in my finance model and it matches. I would appreciate it if someone could help me here is the code

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface BreakDownRepository extends JpaRepository<BreakDown, Long>{
   @Query(value = "select * from break_down as b left join finance as f "
        + "ON b.finance_id = f.finance_id where b.finance_id = :financeId",
        nativeQuery = true)
   List<BreakDown> findByFinanceId(@Param("financeId") Long financeId);
}
```

Finance model

```
@Entity
public class Finance implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "finance_id")
private Long financeId;

@Column(name = "assets")
private int assets;

@Column(name = "profit")
private int profit;

@Column(name = "loss")
private int loss;

@Column(name = "revenue")
private int revenue;

@Column(name = "cost")
private int cost;

@Column(name = "f_date")
private Date fDate;

@Column(name = "currency")
private String currency;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
private Employee employee;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "break_down_id")
private List<BreakDown> breakDown;
//setters getters
```

BreakDown model

```
@Entity
public class BreakDown implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "break_down_id")
private Long breakDownId;

@Column(name = "item")
private String productName;

@Column(name = "cost")
private float price;

private int quantity;

private float total;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
private Finance finance;
//setters getters
```

Error stack trace

```
2021-05-15T04:20:21.606644+00:00 app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name 
finance_finance_id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

Thank you in advance all answers are appreciated

Comment: You are trying to run a native query against the `break_down` table, which has no `finance_id` column.  What is your goal here?

Comment: So should I add the @Column(name = "finance_id") in the BreakDown model?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do.  Please add sample data.

Comment: I am trying to select all data in breakDown table that has the same finance_id

Comment: Go into Postgres and check the table structure.  If you want to do this via a native query, you might have to use a join.

Comment: So I would do the query like this? select * from break_down as b left join finance as f ON b.finance_id = f.finance_id I have tested this in postgre and it works

Comment: The error still remains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneToMany & ManyToOne mapping JPA / Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416970/onetomany-manytoone-mapping-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: @Alex This worked thank you ver much I did not think that it was a mapping error

Comment: @Alex it worked but it didn't retrieved the finance table it only retrieved the BreakDown table

Comment: Cause your native query doesn't retreive it. You should change it or just remove, so it will be generated with hibernate according your method name

Comment: @Alex oh wait the native query in the post is not updated let me update it first

Comment: @Alex there I have updated the native query

Comment: Try to remove query and rename method as @PatelRomil answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JPA

```
List<BreakDown> findAllByFinanceFinanceId(Long financeId);
```

In the case of native query you have to use the JOIN ON *break_down* and *finance* table

---

**UPDATE:**

You should get the Finance details using the get method inside the BreakDown class. I have added the example for the same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private Set<B> b = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<B> getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public A b(Set<B> b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    public A addB(B b) {
        this.b.add(b);
        b.setA(this);
        return this;
    }

    public A removeB(B b) {
        this.b.remove(b);
        version.setA(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setB(Set<B> b) {
        this.b= b;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    ....

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("b")
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public B a(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Query inside `BRepositoty`:

```
List<B> findAllByAId(Long id);
```

You can get the details of `A` using `b.getA()`

Comment: Hi I have tried your solution and it still did not work the error is this org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column breakdown0_.finance_finance_id does not exist

Comment: @CedrixCedrix Have you removed the custom query before using the above method?

Comment: Yes I have @Patel Romil

Comment: Can you share the updated code and database schema for the given table

Comment: it has already been solved thanks to the comment of Alex it was a mapping error I did not think that you needed the mappedBy on a OneToMany relation thanks a bunch

Comment: it worked but it didn't retrieved the finance table it only retrieved the BreakDown table

Comment: You can get the Finance using the `getFinance()` method inside BreakDown class. I have added the more details on the relationship and it should work fine