# I have a problem with entityManagerFactory in my spring project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-2

I have a problem with entityManagerFactory in my spring project. When i start the project i am getting a fault whit the 'entityManagerFactory'

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-05 13:34:46.310 ERROR 1081 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.softuni.ebank.entities.BankAccount, at table: transactions, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(from_account)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.softuni.ebank.EbankApplication.main(EbankApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.softuni.ebank.entities.BankAccount, at table: transactions, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(from_account)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.softuni.ebank.entities.BankAccount, at table: transactions, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(from_account)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The last error in the stacktrace is pretty speaking: `Could not determine type for: com.softuni.ebank.entities.BankAccount, at table: transactions, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(from_account)]`. Maybe you can analyze from there? Or provide more code of the mentioned classes

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774245/4934324): put your hibernate annotations on your fields if you configure hibernate to use fields. I just searched for `Could not determine type for hibernate` on google and that question and answer came up, maybe try googling a bit more next time