# How to map a collection Map<String,List<String>> type using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

**The question was to persist the following class using Hibernate .**

```
Public class Album{
Private int albumid;
Private String aname;
Private Map<String,List<String>> photos;
}
```

I have Tried this

```
@Entity
public class Album {
    @Id
    private int albumId;
    @Column(name= "Album_Name")
    private String aname;
    
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name= "Event_Name")
    @Column(name="Values")
    private Map<String, List<String>> photos;
```

But it is showing errors such as

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Album_photos, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(Values)]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:315)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.IndexedCollection.validate(IndexedCollection.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
        at com.wipro.Insert.main(Insert.java:17)
```

Comment: There is no such annotations,you have to create new `class` for photos and  use hibernate mappings like `@OnetoMany` ,this will create 2 tables.

Comment: Kindly check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mapping is not going to work in Hibernate ORM.

The reason is that you are trying to have two nested collections of elements and this is not supported by Hibernate ORM (first collection is the `Map` and the second collection is the the `List`).

You have to use entities.

You can obtain something similar to an `@ElementCollection` with the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public static class PhotoEvent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Event_Name")
    public String eventName;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "`Values`")
    public List<String> values;

    @ManyToOne
    public Album album;
...
// getter/setter/hascode/equals...
}


@Entity
public static class Album {
    ...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "album", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "eventName")
    public Map<String, PhotoEvent> photoEvents;
    
    ...
}
```

Note that I set `FetchType.EAGER` because it emulates an `@ElementCollection` but you will probably want to set it to `LAZY` (the default).

You will find more details about this type of mapping [in the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-map).