# Hibernate PersistenceException (OneToMany)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entity

```
 @Entity(name = "attribut")
    public class AttributEntity {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "IdAttribut", nullable = false, length = 100)          
        private String idAttribut;
                ....
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attributEntity")
       private List<LiaisonAttributProduitEntity> liaisonAttributList;
                ....
                ....
    }
```

the association entity :

```
@Entity(name = "attribut_produit")
public class LiaisonAttributProduitEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdAttributProduit")
    private Integer idAttributProduit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAttribut")
    private AttributEntity attributEntity;
}
```

I don't know why my mapping doesnt work, i got the `PersistenceUnit: dbEntityManager] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: attribut, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(liaisonAttributList)]` error..

liaisonAttributList is mapped with the AttributeEntity using attributeEntity, so i dont really see where the problem is.

Comment: @JoinColumn should be removed

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at   I think this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all annotations except the `@OneToMany` from `private List<LiaisonAttributProduitEntity> liaisonAttributList;`.