# Hibernate mapping exception for List field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an oracle table `MYTABLE` which has 3 columns as mentioned below.

```
|id | myclob_column | column3|
```

It has one column (`myclob_column`) which is clob data (json). Sample clob data is below.

```
{
"id" : 10001
"name" : "Rahul",
"keyvalue" : [ {"key" : "100", "value" : "A"}, {"key" : "200", "value" : "B"} .....]
}
```

KeyValue is defined as a class in my project like below.

```
@Data
public class KeyValue {

 private String key;
 private String value;

}
```

I am using `org.hibernate.annotations.Formula` annotations on `name` & `keyvalue` field.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
public class MyEntity {

@Id
private String id;

@Formula("JSON_VALUE(myclob_column, '$.name')")
private String name;

@Formula("JSON_VALUE(myclob_column, '$.keyvalue[*]')")
private List<KeyValue> keyvalue;

}
```

While running the `Spring Boot` application, I am getting error for `keyvalue` field and application is not getting started for this.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: MYTABLE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Formula(JSON_VALUE(myclob_column, '$.keyvalue[*]'))]
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: College, for columns: \[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(students)\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at)

Comment: I already checked that but it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: You have not stated the version of Hibernate.

Comment: @GavinKing Hibernate version is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if you're using Hibernate 5, there's simply no built-in support for mapping JSON to `List`s and I'm really not sure what gave you the impression that this would work.

You could, in principle, handle this yourself by writing a `UserType`. (It might even be possible to solve the problem using a JPA `AttributeConverter` but I can't be sure without trying it for myself.)

Now, in Hibernate **6**, the situation is a *little* bit different, there actually is support for mapping some collections to JSON.
For example, the following *is* supported:

```java
@JdbcTypeCode(JSON)
List<String> point;
```

However, as of Hibernate 6.2, the element type must be a basic type. There's not yet support for mapping, say `List<KeyValue>` where `KeyValue` is an embeddable type. I *do* expect that Christian or someone else will work on that *eventually*, but it is not there today.

So the short answer is that what you're trying to do isn't directly supported in any version of Hibernate, but that you should be able to make it work using a `UserType`.