Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Property '' is not a collection and may not be a '@OneToMany', '@ManyToMany', or '@ElementCollection'
I'm trying to create a system to help manage company I'm in. One of the module is ticketing problems. Previously I was using nonSQL DB but decided to learn something new. I'm not sure if it's a problem with classes or just wrong sql model. I want users to be able to create Tickets and be able to Comment them. But all I got is errors.
I have:
User.java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // identyfikator
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String jobPosition; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String department; 
    @Column(nullable = false)  
    private String shortDep; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String deskNumber; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String mobileNumber; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isPrivate; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password; 
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comment> comments;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Session session;
...
}

Ticket.java
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User owner;
    @Column
    private DateTime postedTime;
    @Column
    private String text;
    @ManyToOne
    private User assignedUser;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comment> comments;
...
}

Comment.java
@Entity
public class Comment {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User owner;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticketId")
    private Ticket ticket;
    
    @Column
    private String text;

...
}

Session.java
@Entity
public class Session {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;
    @Column
    private DateTime expTime;
}

Error I got:
ERROR 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Property 'com.Comment.ticket' is not a collection and may not be a '@OneToMany', '@ManyToMany', or '@ElementCollection'
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.826Z  WARN 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Property 'com.Comment.ticket' is not a collection and may not be a '@OneToMany', '@ManyToMany', or '@ElementCollection'
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.826Z  INFO 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.862Z  INFO 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.864Z  INFO 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.871Z  INFO 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
ticket_sys  |
ticket_sys  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ticket_sys  | 2024-12-23T09:54:07.879Z ERROR 1 --- [ticket_sys_backend] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
ticket_sys  |
ticket_sys  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Property 'com.Comment.ticket' is not a collection and may not be a '@OneToMany', '@ManyToMany', or '@ElementCollection'
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:970) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar!/:3.4.0]
ticket_sys  |       at sz.backend.System_zgloszen_backend.SystemZgloszenBackendApplication.main(SystemZgloszenBackendApplication.java:10) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
ticket_sys  |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
ticket_sys  |       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:102) ~[zgloszenia.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:64) ~[zgloszenia.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:40) ~[zgloszenia.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
ticket_sys  | Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property 'com.Comment.ticket' is not a collection and may not be a '@OneToMany', '@ManyToMany', or '@ElementCollection'
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.determineSemanticJavaType(CollectionBinder.java:1121) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.determineCollectionClassification(CollectionBinder.java:1013) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.createBinderAutomatically(CollectionBinder.java:855) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bindCollection(CollectionBinder.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindProperty(PropertyBinder.java:897) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.buildProperty(PropertyBinder.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.processElementAnnotations(PropertyBinder.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(EntityBinder.java:1086) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:401) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.6.2.Final.jar!/:6.6.2.Final]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:419) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:400) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1849) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar!/:6.2.0]
ticket_sys  |       ... 20 common frames omitted

I've searched few guides and tutorial but doesn'y seem to work on my porject. Not sure if relationship XML is necessary or nah. I'd appreciate any help.

You are mixing up annotations. @ManyToOne goes on the single side of things, @OneToMany goes on the collection side of things. You are mixing those up (and that is exactly what the error is telling yuo including the field that has the wrong annotation).

@M.Deinum thanks seems that kinda worked, now I got
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Association 'com.model.User.comments' targets the type 'java.util.List' which is not an '@Entity' type
I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at but doesn't seem to work

Which is exactly the same issue as you used @ManyToOne where you should have used @OneToMany, which will then fix that, next fail on Ticket which has the same problem. As stated @ManyToOne is for the single property of things @OneToMay is for the collection property.

I did change that in,
In User I have:
   @OneToMany(targetEntity=Comment.class, mappedBy = "owner" ,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)     @JsonManagedReference     private List<Comment> comments;     @JsonIgnore     private Session session; 

Which one as there 2 problematic fields. I really suggest first to read some documentation instead of randomly trying out slapping annotations on.

There is a problem in mapping part among User, Ticket, Comment and lastly Session.
Here is the solution way shown below
1 ) @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationships should be revised
A Comment references a User and Ticket using @ManyToOne.
User and Ticket have @OneToMany relationships with Comment.
2 ) JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference should be used
Prevent circular references during JSON serialization.
3 ) Date column should be revised
Replaced DateTime with LocalDateTime
Here is codes snippet shown below
User entity
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; 
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String jobPosition; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String department; 
    @Column(nullable = false)  
    private String shortDep; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String deskNumber; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String mobileNumber; 
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isPrivate; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Session session;
}

Ticket Entity
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime postedTime;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assigned_user_id")
    private User assignedUser;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

Comment Entity
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User owner;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Ticket ticket;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;
}

Session Entity
@Entity
public class Session {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expTime;
}

